# Working directly on network drives cause lags

Tags: networking, mappeddrive

i have a problem with network drives. Users are working directly on files in network drive (mostly graphic files like .ai, .psd etc. from adobe). Drives are mapped via gpo from another server (shared folders on server b are mapped to users on server a). It doeasn't matter if file is large or small. The problem is that when they'are editing file it's lagging, u need to wait several second to scroll down, open tab in program eg. view in InDesign. However, it does not happen all the time. I was checking if maybe network traffic is busy on disk server, but the traffic is normal. Do u have any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Working on a central filestorage has many points for failure. I think the only way you can get behind this is very good monitoring so you can correlate the lags. CPU, Network, Disk, Locks, Background processes. Log what you can log.

Maybe in the long run you can try to establish a version controll system instead of a fileshare.

Comment: @ChristopherPerrin so maybe i should try to use zabbix and see what's going on? or there are any built in functions in win server 2019 that i can use?

Comment: Some things you can check with the inbuilt performance monitor. But central monitoring of any kind is always good.